# How to add fields to the Laravel Backpack 4.0 registration page?

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I have installed Laravel 6 with Backpack 4 and would like to add fields to the registration form, any idea what is the best way of doing this please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To add fields to the registration page you have to override the register.blade.php (to add the fields in html) and the Auth/RegisterController to setup the validations etc.

Don't forget you will need also to add those fields to the model $fillable property.

Best,

Pedro

Comment: Thanks Pedro, I gave up on the product, not enough fast support(as part of the license cost). thanks again for your help.